# Video Not Playing Good In IE

Tags: video, html5-video, flash, mp4, video.js

Hi I Have a video [here](http://thesuperheroblueprint.com) playing good in IE and Mozilla, but when I open the page in IE and played the video.. the video is not playing well as the video playing in chrome? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, with an installation fresh as of today (January 24th, 2013) relating to IE9 playing an MP4 file.  The video's playing fine for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but it's not starting with IE.